# How to push an objects into an array inside another root array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, lodash

I am working with GPS related program so I am actively receiving many location objects. This is the array form I would want to achieve. Initially it should be an empty array and then start with only one child, all incoming location objects would be stored in that one child until some other command is issued. When next event starts, all incoming objects would be stored in second child array, hope you get the gists.

```js
rootArray = [
  [
    {lat: '', long: ''},
    {lat: '', long: ''},
    {lat: '', long: ''},
  ],
  [
    {lat: '', long: ''},
    {lat: '', long: ''},
    {lat: '', long: ''},
  ]
]
```

This is what I have tried but did not succeed.

```js
// I am working with redux here actually
// rootArray: []

case NEW_LOCATION_OBJECT_COMING:
  return {
    ...state,
    rootArray: state.rootArray[state.rootArray.length].concat(action.payload.locationObject),
  }
```

Comment: can't you just change `concat` to `push`?  `state.rootArray[state.rootArray.length].push(action.payload.locationObject)`

Comment: Do not use `push` that will mutate the array, `concat` on the other hand is a good method that returns a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in the array are indexed from `0` to `length - 1`, so if you try to access the element at index `length` you will get `undefined`. We should do this:

```
...
rootArray: [
  ...state.rootArray.slice(0, state.rootArray.length - 1),
  state.rootArray[state.rootArray.length - 1].concat(action.payload.locationObject)
],
...
```

The reason is that with the previous approach we were assigning to the `rootArray` the result of concatenating its last element with the payload, so everything else would get lost and our `rootArray` would become just a simple array of objects.

We need to preserve what we have by extending the existing array, to achieve this I create a new array that looks like the old `rootArray` without the last element, the new last element is then the concatenation of the old last element and the payload. I hope it makes sense.

**EDIT**
Given your comment it depends on how you initiate your `rootArray` if it's just an empty array then this approach fails and instead you should do:

```
...
rootArray: [
  ...state.rootArray.slice(0, state.rootArray.length - 1),
  state.rootArray.length > 0
    ? state.rootArray[state.rootArray.length - 1].concat(action.payload.locationObject)
    : [...action.payload.locationObject]
],
...
```

Otherwise you can just initiate the `rootArray` to `[[]]` and use the the first version.

Comment: I still got that error, its like it does not recognised rootArray

Comment: You should use redux dev tools to debug this, the way you updated the state was wrong to begin with but if `state.rootArray` is `undefined` then there is something else wrong. Try and debug it or log what `state.rootArray` is before dispatching the action.

Comment: I tried, it's just an empty array and it should not fail right

Comment: I edited, I forgot the `length - 1` on the second part, if it's an empty array then it's normal it fails, there is nothing at `rootArray[rootArray.length - 1]`, I suppose your `initialState` is `rootArray: []`, change it to `rootArray:[[]]`.

Comment: I did some research of the slice method but I don't understand the reason of using it here. I have adapted the first version of the code from you and it works as intended, but when next event starts, it will just keep concats to the first child of the rootArray rather than starting second childArray and move on from there. I suspect something is off with that slice method though... hmm

Comment: Well the `slice` method is supposed to return a NEW array that is a "slice" of the old array going from the first given index (`0`) up to second one (excluded) so in our case `...length - 2`. I will try and create a quick snippet to verify it works as intended. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ADYn0J3ol try play with this, seems to be working fine to me, I want to make sure this is the behavior you wanted

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty close to what I required! Had to made some modifications to fit in a different nature I have in my app :)